# Android Drag and drop between 2 fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, drag-and-drop

I have 2 fragments.

I want to drag a view from fragment one and drop it to another view in fragment two.

What i do now is i start dragging (using drag and drop api) inside fragment one , then i hide fragment one then i show  fragment two which has a drag listener event on some view.

I use fragment transactions of add and show and hide to make sure that the fragments are not destroyed or recreated , i never use replace for transaction.

However the onDrag method in drag listener interface inside fragment two is never called when i hide fragment one and show fragment two.

I have done something similar before that worked , except that fragment two was overlapping fragment one and both appeared on UI , and when i start dragging inside fragment one i only hided it then the drag listener inside fragment two was active .

So the difference in the case that worked was that i only hided fragment one by transaction.

However in the case which is not working i hide fragment one and show fragment two by transaction.

Don't know why are the results different.

For further details on my case i'm using BottomNavigationView and it has 3 fragments , i'm trying to drag and drop between 2 of those fragments.

Comment: did you try passing your dragging event from fragment one to fragment two?

Comment: @stallianz do you mean pass the view object and start dragging from fragment two ?

Comment: @stallianz well , what do you know it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by sending the view object via event bus to fragment two ( after the user in my case long pressed on the view in fragment one ).

Then i switched fragments as mentioned in the question.

Then i started using the drag and drop api from fragment two event bus receiver that contains my view object.